# plot of a function containing integral

Tags: probability-theory, graphing-functions, characteristic-functions

[image]

I have solved the problem. I want to see plot of $f(x)$ for different $n$. But I don't have any tool (software application) to do that. Can anyone please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An R solution:

```
f <- function(x, n) {
  u <- function(t) {(sin(t)/t)^n * cos(t*x)}
  integrate(u, 0, Inf, subdivisions = 2000)$value
}
f <- Vectorize(f)
curve(f(x, n = 2), from = -5, to = 5)
```

[image]

```
curve(f(x, n = 5), from = -6, to = 6)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, I downloaded R, applied you algo. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in Matlab: see [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/276391-how-to-plot-a-function-containing-an-integral). However, it requires certain knoweledge on programming it. Actually, [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/) accepts integral functions- and it is very easy to use. I don't know, however, if it accepts general improper integrals.

Comment: sorry, I don't know matlab.

Comment: Edited it with an interesting addition.

Answer (score 1):

Here are plots for n=1,2,3 (more can be produced at your request, but they took a while to load). There were made on Mathematica 11 with the code (`n` was varied):

```
Plot[(1/Pi)*Integrate[(Sin[t]/t)^n*Cos[t*x], {t, 0, Infinity}], 
    {x, -1, 1},PlotRange -> {0, 1}
    ]
```

n=1:

[image]

n=2:

[image]

n=3:

[image]